# Aligning a list of links to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a list of links to the right. The code breaks when the parent div width gets larger.

For example, in the code below div `width=700px` looks good:

[image: width=700px]

but `width=800px` it looks like this:

[image: width=800px]

**HTML:**

```
<div class='linksArea' style="width: 800px;">
    <div class="boxLeft"></div>

    <a href="google.com">Link1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="google.com">Link2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="google.com">Link3</a>
    <br>
    <a href="google.com">Link4</a>
    <br>
    <a href="google.com">Link5</a>
    <br>
    <a href="google.com">Link6</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boxLeft {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: green;
     float:left;
}

.linksArea {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.linksArea a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 20em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: .6em;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    float:right;
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you use an ordered list or unordered list for your links?

Comment: Put the links into an additional container element, and float that instead of the individual links.

Comment: I prefer not to. Do you think this issue is list-specific?

Comment: Use a percentage value instead of having 800px

Comment: Make .linksArea float:right....currently float:right is for .linksArea a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930317/how-to-pin-elements-on-the-right). Check the accepted answer there anyway to see if it solves your problem

Comment: It's related, but more general. The cleanest solution to this one is to use clear:right;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `clear:right` to your `.linksArea a` CSS:

```
.linksArea a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 20em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: .6em;
    padding-bottom: .6em;
    clear:right;
    float:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s9rXz/)**

Adding the clear ensures that the element has to stay below the other right floated elements before it, and the existing float will push it to the right like the others.

Comment: Perfect! I actually tried "clear:both;" before, but "clear:right;" is what solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the problem. The floats are still jumping out of the container. You will see it when you try to add background color to the parent.

Comment: @jacelysh - First, the OP said it solves the problem. Second, where does the OP say he needs a background color, which is a different issue, with an equally simple solution?

Comment: The background color is just to show how the parent behaves relative to the contents. If it's contents are still jumping out of the container then it may cause some problem on the layout in the future. Adding a clearfix after the last anchor tag might totally solve it.

Comment: @jacelysh - What background color are you referring to? The containing div has no background color. Also, nothing is jumping anywhere. Downvoting over something the OP isn;t concerned with makes no sense. Plus clearfix is a hack. Adding `overflow:auto` on the containing linksArea div is the preferred solution to containing floated children.